# sendPoll to Telegram from Google Sheets App Script with open_period time and reply_markup buttons

Tags: google-sheets, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I've already this code working to send Polls from a Google Sheet, but I want to add the `open_period` for one day, and if it is possible add the `reply_markup` option to add buttons to choose the answer instead of a list, and plus, how can I read the JSON possible answers form a cell and not defined by `var answers = ['✌️ VOY', 'NO PUEDO IR', 'POSIBLEMENTE SI VAYA'];`?

```
function sendPoll() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("DATA");
var question = sheet.getRange("B1").getValues();
//var answers = sheet.getRange("B2").getValues(); //How can I read the poll answers from a cell?
var answers = ['✌️ VOY', 'NO PUEDO IR', 'POSIBLEMENTE SI VAYA']; 
var bot = sheet.getRange("B3").getValues();
var chatId = sheet.getRange("B4").getValues();


    var payload = {
      "method": 'sendPoll',
      "chat_id": String(chatId),
      "question": String(question),
      "parse_mode": 'HTML',
      "options": JSON.stringify(answers),
      "is_anonymous": false,
      "type": 'regular',
      "allows_multiple_answers": false,
      "open_period": 0
    }
    var data = {
        "method": "post",
        "payload": payload,
        "muteHttpExceptions":true
    };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot + '/', data);
  Logger.log(response);
};
```

Comment: Assuming value in `B2` is `["✌️ VOY", "NO PUEDO IR", "POSIBLEMENTE SI VAYA"]`, `var answers = JSON.parse(sheet.getRange("B2:B4").getValue());`

Comment: How do the `B1`, `B2`, `B3` and `B4` cells look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variable for each option and use them in answers . I have little modify this code and this is working.

```
function sendPoll() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("DATA");
var question = sheet.getRange("B1").getValues();
var option1 = sheet.getRange("C1").getValues();
var option2 = sheet.getRange("C2").getValues();
var option3 = sheet.getRange("C3").getValues();
var option4 = sheet.getRange("C4").getValues();
var answers = [''+option1+'', ''+option2+'', ''+option3+'', ''+option4+''];
var bot = sheet.getRange("B3").getValues();
var chatId = sheet.getRange("B4").getValues();
var explanation = sheet.getRange("B4").getValues();

    var payload = {
      "method": 'sendPoll',
      "chat_id": String(chatId),
      "question": String(question),
      "parse_mode": 'HTML',
      "options": JSON.stringify(answers),
      "is_anonymous": true,
      "type": 'quiz',
      "allows_multiple_answers": false,
      "open_period": 0,
      "correct_option_id": 1,
      "explanation": String(explanation)
    }
    var data = {
        "method": "post",
        "payload": payload,
        "muteHttpExceptions":true
    };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot + '/', data);
  Logger.log(response);
};
```